# select records inserted in last 20 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have fairly simple table, in which the field lastloginon is timestamp and the date stored in it looks like this: 2013-03-17 17:12:58

How can i select all records that are isnerted in last 20 minutes?

I am trying with the following code:

```
 SELECT * FROM who_is_online WHERE lastloginon > (now() - interval 20 minute)
```

which produce wrong set of results that is event the qyery is executed at 15:30 it display 4 records which are inserted at:

```
2013-03-18 13:13:36
2013-03-18 13:35:12
2013-03-18 14:43:42
2013-03-18 14:55:34
```

Anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Here is the table export, just in hope that someone can spot what i am doing wrong:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `who_is_online` (
  `recid` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `lastloginon` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `memberip` varchar(255) default NULL,
  `sessionid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(4) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`recid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `who_is_online`
--

INSERT INTO `who_is_online` (`recid`, `username`, `lastloginon`, `memberip`, `sessionid`, `active`) VALUES
(7, ' admin', '2013-03-17 14:43:43', '87.202.163.222', '7kve2idmdbd47aksab4j9hqg74', 1),
(8, ' mmitechnic', '2013-03-17 15:16:39', '5.54.84.144', 'mofgpldp2lu30enhitvak9m4t3', 1),
(9, ' theodor71', '2013-03-17 17:12:58', '85.75.243.246', '4enpk49oi7cg0blumgsd0lu0m7', 1),
(10, ' xElfiex', '2013-03-18 12:38:05', '5.55.27.203', 'tr003d6qbd71v2i5grnuako362', 1),
(11, ' admin', '2013-03-18 12:56:06', '85.74.166.110', '7kve2idmdbd47aksab4j9hqg74', 1),
(12, ' xElfiex', '2013-03-18 13:13:36', '5.55.27.203', 'tr003d6qbd71v2i5grnuako362', 1),
(13, ' admin', '2013-03-18 13:35:12', '85.74.166.110', '7kve2idmdbd47aksab4j9hqg74', 1),
(14, ' admin', '2013-03-18 14:43:42', '85.74.166.110', '7kve2idmdbd47aksab4j9hqg74', 1),
(15, ' admin', '2013-03-18 14:55:34', '85.74.166.110', '7kve2idmdbd47aksab4j9hqg74', 1),
(16, ' admin', '2013-03-18 15:32:27', '85.74.166.110', '7kve2idmdbd47aksab4j9hqg74', 1);
```

Regards,Zoran

Comment: What do you get from `SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE`?

Comment: what should be the output?

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211461/how-to-find-a-time-delta-of-a-datatime-row-in-mysql

it uses mysql's TIMEDIFF

Comment: select now() - interval 20 minute return all results, which is wierd...

Comment: @Zoran please answer my question so I can help you

Comment: Explosion Pills, the query  SELECT * FROM who_is_online WHERE NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE returns all results from dataabse

Comment: @ExplosionPills is hoping you will run *precisely* this query: `SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE`

Comment: The question may be a duplicate, but there's no way it's a duplicate of the question marked in the closing notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try `date_sub(now(), interval 20 minute)` instead of `(now() - interval 20 minute)`

Comment: `SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE` actually works properly for me; may depend on the MySQL version though.

Comment: Query $query ="SELECT * FROM who_is_online WHERE date_sub(now(), interval 20 minute)"; return all 10 records,and 3 of those records are from yesterday. What on earth i am doing wrong??

Comment: no like this: SELECT * FROM who_is_online WHERE lastloginon > date_sub(now(), interval 20 minute). Or try what @ExplosionPills said also, something like SELECT * FROM who_is_online WHERE lastloginon > (SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)

Comment: SELECT *
FROM who_is_online
WHERE `lastloginon` > ( NOW( ) - INTERVAL 20
MINUTE )
LIMIT 0 , 30  returns 4 records which are way off the mark of 20 minutes. 2013-03-18 13:35:12   is one of them

Comment: how about the first one: SELECT * FROM who_is_online WHERE lastloginon > date_sub(now(), interval 20 minute) - did it worked or not?

Comment: I just edit the post, and i included the table that i am workng on, so maybe one can spot the mistake there....

Comment: Gerald ,the quyery returns 3 records, and the last login times are:2013-03-18 14:43:42,2013-03-18 14:55:34,2013-03-18 15:32:27

Comment: I think I knew what's wrong, read this http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/123332 . date_sub works only with datetime type, your lastloginon is of type timestamp. Try changing that to datetime, and it shall work

Comment: I will check that right now Gerald

Comment: Gerald, the change to datetime still show wrong results. Two that should be displayed and 3 that should not. i really have no idea how can i get out of this mess.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you may have a timezone issue.  It's hard to tell without knowing more about your server and client configuration.

But you might try this WHERE clause ...

```
   lastloginon >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (20  * 60)
```

This will compare your column numerically to the unix timestamp of twenty minutes ago.

Comment: Hi Ollie Indeed, i have different timezone on the servier and on the site i have to display different time. So when i insert the records,i use the following code $lastlogin = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$lastlogin + 2 hours"));

Comment: SELECT *
FROM who_is_online
WHERE lastloginon >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( ) - ( 20 *60 )
LIMIT 0 , 30 return all records

Comment: OK, that's the confusion. TIMESTAMP datatypes are automatically converted from the timezone setting of your MySQL connection to UTC when stored into the database, and automatically converted back when displayed on the client.   So you're storing timestamps that are two hours in the future into your table.

Answer (score 0):

The time on the mysql server is different than what you probably expect it to be. 
In order to find the time on the server try using this query:

```
select now();
```

Now, your query is correct, but your insert to the table is incorrect. Instead of using

```
$lastlogin = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$lastlogin + 2 hours"));
```

on the site side,  leave this field empty and use your `"default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"`.

on a different note, pay attention to the fact that username has an unexplained leading space.